# Change Windows Powershell transcript headers

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the Start-Transcript command to capture stdout of my Powershell scripts, and I'm getting this header:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20190717150208
Username: <Something
RunAs User: <Something>
Configuration Name: 
Machine: <Something> (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17134.0)
Host Application: <Something> <Something>
Process ID: 16652
PSVersion: 5.1.17134.858
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17134.858
BuildVersion: 10.0.17134.858
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
```

Now, I'm trying to change the Start Time header to be with the format: MM-dd-HH-mm.
There's any way to do so without reading the entire text?

I want the Start time and End time of transcript will be:

> Start time: 07/17/15/_17/08,
>   End time: 07/17/15_17/30

Comment: Not without manually re-writing the transcript files after the fact

Comment: So the only possible way to achieve this goal is to read the entire transcript and rewrite the Start and End times?

Comment: Yes, that is correct :)